# How to toggle a circle on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to ensure that when an image is clicked a circle will appear on the image. However, when I try the code like it currently is, I'm unable to see images that are generated by my code below. I'm not exactly sure how to fix it or what to do.

Edit: 
So I got the image and the canvas to be attached to each div. However, my every image you click on will activate the canvas only on the first image. For example, if you click image two and three, two canvas' will be filled on image one. The only way to remove these canvas' is to click on the canvas area twice. Once for each time it was applied to on other images. This only happens if `cnvs.style.position = 'absolute';` is enabled. If it is commented out, the canvas will connect itself to bottom of the image instead of being overlaid.

```js
 document.body.onload = addElement;

      function addElement() {



            var i = 0;
            // create a new div element 
            const imagePath = <?= json_encode($face) ?>;
            //   console.log(imagePath);
            for (const image of imagePath) {
                  var id = `${image}`;

                  const img = document.createElement("img");
                  img.src = `/check/assets/img/${image}`;
                  img.classList.add("new");

                  const cnvs = document.createElement("canvas");
                  cnvs.classList.add("suiteiCanvas");

                  cnvs.style.left = img.offsetLeft + "px";
                  cnvs.style.top = img.offsetTop + "px";

                 
                  var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
                  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
                  ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
                  ctx.stroke();

                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  div.id = id;
                  div.classList.add("image");


                  




                  linebreak = document.createElement("br");

                  document.getElementById('suitei-slider').appendChild(div);
                  document.getElementById(image).appendChild(img);
                  document.getElementById(image).appendChild(cnvs);

           



                  cnvs.onclick = function() {
                        cnvs.style.display = 'none';
                        hdnName.value = null;
                  };
                  img.onclick = function() {
                        cnvs.style.display = '';
                        hdnName.value = img.id;
                  };

            }





      }
```

```css
canvas.suiteiCanvas{
  height: auto; 
  width: auto;
  /* position: absolute;
  display: 'none'; */
max-height: 200px;
max-width: 150px;

margin-left: 100px; 
margin-right: 100px;
border:3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
}


img.new {
 
 
  height: auto; 
  width: auto;

max-height: 200px;
max-width: 150px;

margin-left: 100px; 
margin-right: 100px;
border:3px solid rgb(20, 11, 11);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="multiple-items" id="suitei-slider"></div>
```

Thanks for any help!

This is the code I'm using for reference

```js
var img = document.getElementById("theImg");
var cnvs = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var hdnName = document.getElementById("sendServ");

cnvs.style.position = "absolute";
cnvs.style.left = img.offsetLeft + "px";
cnvs.style.top = img.offsetTop + "px";
cnvs.style.display = 'none';


var ctx = cnvs.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
ctx.stroke();

function draw(){
  cnvs.style.display = '';
  hdnName.value = img.id;
}

function remove() {
 cnvs.style.display = 'none';
  hdnName.value = null;
}
```

```css
#draw-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 16px 3px 16px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<img id='theImg' src='https://blogs.worldbank.org/sites/default/files/africacan/small_better_small.jpg' onclick='draw()'>
<canvas id='myCanvas' width='536px' height='536px' onclick="remove()"></canvas>

<input type="hidden" id="sendServ">
```

Comment: @Barudar - It's linked there in the question. But please don't ask for off-site examples, ask for **on-site** ones (see above).

Comment: The linked fiddle seems to work? You have no canvas defined but cnvs so try `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cnvs.width, cnvs.height);`

Comment: ... and set the width/height on cnvs!

Comment: Do you get errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Lajos 
Thanks for the tip! I got it to work! However, my canvas' are stuck to the bottom of my images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to

```
document.getElementById(image).apppendChild(cnvs);
```

and, assuming that image is the `id` of an `img` tag, this effectively means that you try to append a `canvas` as a child of an `img`, which is invalid. If you look at the code you have used as a model, you can see that it's not appending a `canvas` tag as a child of an `img` tag, but rather it is displaying an image inside a `canvas`. So, the problem is that you structurally attempt to put the `canvas` inside the `img` instead of drawing your `img` inside your `canvas`, as the model code does.

Comment: @user11571537 It's a bit unfair to change your question to something quite different after Lajos answered your original one. You should post a new question.